# UWP fill a List via Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, uwp

Im currently trying to fill a List in my UWP Project with data from a Webservice.
I have testet this code:

```
public void test()
{
       BasicHttpBinding basicAuthBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
        basicAuthBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        EndpointAddress basicAuthEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("myURI");

        LiveOdi.getODI_v1_PortTypeClient ptc = new LiveOdi.getODI_v1_PortTypeClient(basicAuthBinding, basicAuthEndpoint);

        ptc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myUsername";
        ptc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myPasswort";

        ptc.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

        string = ptc.getODIAsync("1").ToString();

}
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        test();

        textBlock.Text = string;
    }
```

When I click the button to receive the data and display it , my Textblock only displays : 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task´1[Test.LiveOdi.getODIResponse]

The same code works fine in forms with datagrid.datasource set to ptc.GetODI("1").

Edit : 
Due to a bug (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/84024ccf-7ef2-493e-a7bb-c354f42a354d/does-uwp-10-support-soap-services?forum=wpdevelop) I cannot use this approach anymore.
Can someone name an alternativ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ptc.getODIAsync("1")` is async, and is returning a `Task`. That's why it's being displayed in the `TextBox` (as your code calls `ToString` on the `Task`).

You'll likely need to follow the [`async`/`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) pattern so that you can get the response.

```
public async Task<string> test()
{
     // put all of the web service setup code here, then:

     string result = await ptc.getODIAsync("1");
     return result; 
}

// add async here so that the Click event can use Tasks with await/async
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // stuff the value when the response returns from test
    textBlock.Text = await test();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
But now I get the error :
The typ LiveOdiResponse cannot be convertet to "string" 
I have tryed List<> , int and some other things but nothing seems to work.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for your time but due to a bug its not important anymore ! (see edit)